# Как сделать проверку загрузки?

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

```
 DataInputStream inputStream=new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
 bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
 inputStream.close();
```

Как сделать проверку загрузки? То есть пока идет загрузка, показываем первый текст "Подождите", после "Загрузка успешно прошла"?

Comment: Кто там минусует? Можете объяснить причину?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загрузка данных происходит в потоке, перед загрузкой нужно показать "Подождите" в UI потоке.

А вообще юзайте [AsyncTask](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer)

upd:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      tvInfo.setText("Begin");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
      try {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (String url : urls) {
          // загружаем файл
           TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
          // выводим промежуточные результаты
          publishProgress(++cnt);
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      //Обрабатываем промежуточные результаты
      tvInfo.setText("Downloaded " + values[0] + " files");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.setText("End");
    }
```

Comment: Ну глупо такое писать...вы же должны знать что начиная с 9-10 API, загрузка описанная в самом IU не запуститься. Код в AsyncTask, написан. Еще раз спрошу, как сделать так чтобы когда будет происходить загрузка то можно было видеть её? 1% 5% 98% 100% обычная загрузка, такая загрузка когда вы скачиваете фильм или музыку, я могу в AsyncTask указать Pre and Post, но мне надо сам процесс загрузки. А не начало и конец, так что Pre and Post не подходит...

Comment: Я так и написал, что загрузка данных происходит в потоке(то есть отличном от UI)! Вам стоило написать как вы загружаете данные и чего ждете от программы! В вопросе ничего о AsyncTask и о процессе загрузки!

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант делаешь, как  [тут](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/), только вместо OutputStream пишешь в byte[] и затем преобразуешь в картинку через BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray.

Answer (score 2):

В теории надо знать исходный размер файла, чтобы знать % загрузки. На практике лучше юзать библиотеку, у которой есть методы для получения прогресса... Вот линк этого вопроса на [стэке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog).

Comment: Можно через avialable, но почему то данные не верные отображаются через avialable